# How to restrict publishing to a topic in GCP pub/sub based on number of unacknowledged messages in the queue?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, microservices, azureservicebus, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a topic, which is attached to a listener service that triggers a microservices-based processing pipeline.
I want to restrict the users from publishing a new message on this topic to prevent my system from choking after a certain limit.
For example, if the number of unacknowledged messages in the topic is already more than or equal to 10000, then I want to give a bad input exception or something to restrict users from flooding my queue.

Any leads?
Moreover, it will be a great help if someone knows if this feature is available in the Azure service bus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping the publishing because a subscriber already has a large backlog of messages to process would defeat the purpose of using Pub/Sub as a paradigm. The entire goal is to decouple the publisher and the subscriber so that the publisher behavior does not need to change based on the subscriber's ability to consume messages.

Consider the case where you have multiple subscriptions for the same topic and one builds up a large backlog, but the other does not. Should publishers not be able to publish in this scenario? Why should subscribers for the fast subscription not be able to receive the messages? Additionally, if your publisher gets back errors, what does it do with these messages? Drop them? Enqueue them locally? The whole purpose of Pub/Sub is to handle these cases so that you don't have to.

If your subscribers need to be limited in the number of messages they process at once, then you should use the [subscriber client library flow control mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#flow_control) to prevent them from getting overwhelmed by restricting the maximum number of outstanding messages and/or bytes. Then, they can work through the messages at the rate they are capable of handling. If they can't keep up with the publish load at all, then you either need to bring up more subscriber clients or decide that it's okay for older messages to expire and set your [subscription message retention](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#configuring_message_retention) time accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! this helps. Any idea if how to achieve the flow controller settings in Azure Service Bus?